# How to set bitrate for ffmpeg's native Opus encoder using youtube-dl?

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube-dl

I don't have *libopus* library. According to ffmpeg [docs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-codecs.html#opus)

there is have basic control over bitrate settings.
Passing params to ffmpeg with *-postprocessor-args ARGS*.

*--no-check-certificate --prefer-insecure --extract-audio --audio-format opus --postprocessor-args **-b:a 64K** --external-downloader aria2c --external-downloader-args "-x16 -s16 -k1M"* doesn't do anything.

Comment: Should not the `--postprocessor-args` be quoted the same way the `--external-downloader-args` are?

Answer (score 0):

Works pretty fine for me. Just add some qutation marks around the postprocessor options.

```
--no-check-certificate --prefer-insecure --extract-audio --audio-format opus --postprocessor-args "-b:a 64K" --external-downloader aria2c --external-downloader-args "-x16 -s16 -k1M" doesn't do anything.
```

i can't print it strong, so look at the --postprocessor-args "-b:a 64K" part